# PHP, log ip's and password

Tags: php, logging

So i have a website which people can access buy useing a password.

```
Example:
http://www.MyWebsite.com/?pass=YourPassword
```

I was wondering how to log the ip's in a .txt file with the ?pass that they used.
So that i can see what ip's are used on what password.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the first: passing passwords through url is **very bad idea**. But let's assume that you are passing some other data through `$_GET['pass']`.

Here is described how to get user's IP address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/3845412

Your script should do something like that:

```
$ip = your_function_that_gets_user_ip();
$pass = $_GET['pass'];

file_put contents('file.txt', implode(',', [$pass, $ip]) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

which makes `file.txt` using format like:

```
127.0.0.1,secret    
192.168.137.1,foopassword
```